# Caching data from MySQL DB - technique and appropriate STL container?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, stl, scalability

I am designing a data caching system that could have a very large amount of records held at a time, and I need to know what stl container to use and how to use it.  The application is that I have an extremely large DB of records for users - when they log in to my system I want to pull their record and cache some data such as username and several important properties.  As they interact with the system, I update and access their properties.  Several properties are very volatile and I'm doing this to avoid "banging" on the DB with many transactions.  Also, I rarely need to be using the database for sorting or anything - I'm using this just like a glorified binary save file (which is why I am happy to cache records to memory..); a more important goal for me is to be able to scale to huge numbers of users.

When the user logs out, server shuts down, or **periodically in round-robin fashion (just in case..)**, I want to write their data back to the DB.

The server keeps its own:

```
vector <UserData *> loggedInUsers;
```

With UserData keeping things like username (string) and other properties from the DB, as well as other temporary data like network handles.

My first Q is, if I need to find a specific user in this vector, what's the **fastest** way to do that and is there a different stl container I can use to do this faster?  What I do now is create an iterator, start it at loggedInUsers.begin() and iterate to .end(), checking *iter->username == "foo" and returning when it's found.  If the username is at the end of the vector, or if the vector has 5000 users, this is a significant delay.

My second Q is, how can I round-robin schedule this data to be written back to the DB?  I can call a function every time I'm ready to write a few records to the DB.  But I can't hold an iterator to the vector, because it will become invalid.  What I'd like to do is have a rotating queue where I can access the head of the queue, persist it to the DB, then rotate it to be the end of the queue.  That seems like a lot of overhead.. what type could I use to do this better?

My third Q is, I'm using MySQL server and libmysqlclient connector/C.. is there any kind of built in caching that could solve this problem "for free", or is there a different technique altogether?  I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. you're better off with a map, this is a tree that does the lookup for you. Test with a map and (assuming you have the right compiler) or a hash_map (which does the same thing, but the lookup mechanism is different). They have different performance characteristics for different types of data storage workloads.

A2. A list would probably be better for you - push to the front, pull off the end. (a deque could also be used, but you cannot keep an iterator if you erase from it, you can with a list). [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/) and pop_front (or vice-versa) will allow you to keep a rolling queue of cached data.

A3. You could try SQLite, which is a mini-database designed for simple application-level db storage needs. It can work [entirely in-memory](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) too.

Comment: A1: Thanks.  A2: What about the performance of pull/push, each operation will assume I'm discarding/adding brand new element right?  Is there any data struct that is made to just 'rotate'?  A3: Multiple apps can hit the DB.  Bigger follow up question: A1 and A2 I want to combine in to one thing so that I can hold all this data in a map and rotate through it to persist updates back to the DB.. how can I accomplish that?

Comment: I'm sorry on A3 I realize you're suggesting I use SQLite in-memory as a data structure.  That would be great actually

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your system does or how it's accessed, but this kind of technique probably won't scale well (because eventually you'll run out of memory and whatever you use to find information won't be as efficient as a database) and won't necessarily handle concurrent users properly, unless you make sure that data can be shared properly between them.

That said.. you might be better off using a map (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) with the username as the key.

In terms of writing it back to the database, why not store a separate structure (a queue) that you can clear every time you write it to the database? As long as you're storing pointers it won't use much more memory. Which brings me to.. rather than using pointers you should take a look at smart pointers (for example [boost's shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)) which let you pass them around without worrying about ownership.

Comment: Thanks, good advice, and you're right I could have defined my application better.  My data is small, lets say 64bytes absolute max.  That means in 1GB of RAM I'd have ~16 million users in memory so that's no problem (I'll run out of network socket descriptors first).  I like your idea of just holding the pointers and see what you mean with shared_ptr helping